# vpn in python for the requests module

Tags: python, request, python-requests, vpn

I need to send requests through requests, but the privacy of my address and location is mandatory. Now the question is, how can I connect VPN and Python or provide privacy in a different way?

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent':'my user agent',
           'acept':'*/*'}
print(requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip', headers=headers).text)
```

Comment: `VPN` and `Python` do work on a whole other level. You can connect your network cards via `VPN` but what does this have to do with `Python` ?

Comment: I would like to know if there are any libraries / modules for connecting a free VPN through python code

Comment: You connect with a VPN in your OS then use any software that makes outgoing connections, voilà now you're using Python with a VPN